# Batch File to copy folders from a text file to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file to read off a text file and copy the folder with the files to another directory:

```
set dest=f:\Test
for /f %%i in (C:\dirs.txt) do copy "%%i" %dest%
```

When I run this batch file, only the files copy.  I want to copy the folders with the files.

IE folder\files to destination\folder\files.

Comment: windows - Batch File to copy folders from a text file to another directory - Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `xcopy`.

```
xcopy /?
```

If the text file contains filenames, try:

```
xcopy "%%i" %dest%\ /S
```

If the text file contains only directory names, try:

```
xcopy "%%i\*" %dest%\ /S
```

Comment: yes, xcopy works particularly well when copying a folder to a folder.   its a little tricky copying files to folders, but folders to folders is easy.  "xcopy.exe dirsrc dirdest /Q /F /D "

Comment: basically, if there are files in folder a i want folder a copied to its new destination

Comment: @jeff Then use `/S` instead of `/E`.  Did you read through `xcopy /?` to see how to use it?

Comment: i read the guide and i am still just getting the files with /s.  i am putting the /s after %dest% /S.  i am also using windows 7.

Comment: @Jeff I've edited my answer.  If you supply a trailing `\\` it disambiguates the target type.  It wasn't clear whether your source file contains directory names or file names.  I've provided a command for either.

Comment: Files are still copying over only.  i need to copy both the folder with the files over.

Comment: its stil just copying the files without the folders.

Comment: The difficult thing about this is that it works fine when I do what I've suggested you do.  If it's not working for you, then check that you have copied the command line correctly.  If it still doesn't work, then something else is wrong.  You should try simple test cases by hand without the `for` loop.  Also, do the lines of your input file contain any spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Do you own Vista or later? Then give robocopy a shot: `robocopy "source" "destination" /MIR`. Some other options:

```
             Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").

::
:: Copy options :
::
                 /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
                 /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
             /LEV:n :: only copy the top n LEVels of the source directory tree.

                 /Z :: copy files in restartable mode.
                 /B :: copy files in Backup mode.
                /ZB :: use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.

  /COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY (default is /COPY:DAT).
                       (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps).
                       (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

               /SEC :: copy files with SECurity (equivalent to /COPY:DATS).
           /COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info (equivalent to /COPY:DATSOU).
            /NOCOPY :: COPY NO file info (useful with /PURGE).

             /PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
               /MIR :: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).

               /MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
              /MOVE :: MOVE files AND dirs (delete from source after copying).

       /A+:[RASHNT] :: add the given Attributes to copied files.
       /A-:[RASHNT] :: remove the given Attributes from copied files.

            /CREATE :: CREATE directory tree and zero-length files only.
               /FAT :: create destination files using 8.3 FAT file names only.
               /FFT :: assume FAT File Times (2-second granularity).
               /256 :: turn off very long path (> 256 characters) support.

             /MON:n :: MONitor source; run again when more than n changes seen.
             /MOT:m :: MOnitor source; run again in m minutes Time, if changed.

      /RH:hhmm-hhmm :: Run Hours - times when new copies may be started.
                /PF :: check run hours on a Per File (not per pass) basis.

             /IPG:n :: Inter-Packet Gap (ms), to free bandwidth on slow lines.
```

Thera are more interesting options.

Comment: will robocopy copy files based off a text file

Comment: You can create a `job file` and store it. But this is not text. If you are looking for a pure text solution, you need a batch script, powershell, VB or similar.

Answer (score 0):

before you mess up the files you should probably test it out IE.

```
    @echo off
    CD drive path of parent folder
    mkdir A
    CD ...\A 
    echo hello>1.txt
    echo hello2>2.txt
    mkdir A2
    xcopy A "drive path"
    start explorer.exe "path to A2"
```

this will make a basic folder setup to test it out with.
after that if it works apply it to your files path.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above seem to copy the directory contents to the root of the destination. And have problems with folders that have spaces in them.
try the lines below to solve that...

```
set dest=e:\Test
for /f "delims=" %%i in (folders.txt) do xcopy "%%i\*" "%dest%\%%i\*" /E /F /Y

/E also copies empty subdirectories
/F lists the full filenames to copies (for debugging purposes)
/Y answers questions with yes.
```

Directories that don't exist will be created with this command and it will overwrite files when they exist in the destination.

The delims= part makes sure that the directories read from the textfiles can contain spaces